# pow(i,4) in c giving runtime error

Tags: c, runtime-error, pow

I have a program where i am trying to find the sum of fourth powers of no's till n value

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
    int a,i=1,sum=0;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    do
    {
        sum+=pow(i,4);
        i++;
    }while(i<=a);
    printf("%d",sum);
}
```

When I run the above it is giving *run time error* **"Floating point: stack underflow"** 
I want to use pow() function only. If i use (i*i*i*i) it will work instead. 
I am using **turbo c++ 4.5** and the error is shown while **tracing using f7**. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: what is the smallest value of `a` that breaks?

Comment: Insure `a` is set as expected.  `if (1 != scanf("%d",&a)) Error();`.

Comment: Could you tell us what you entered for `a`?

Comment: Use a debugger or add `printf("%d %d %d\n",a,i,sum);` right before `sum+=pow(i,4);` to know under what conditions the error occurred.

Comment: What platform and compiler are you using?

Comment: Strictly speaking, should the `sum+=pow(i,4);` attempt to create a `sum > INT_MAX`, code may exhibit undefined behavior which includes "Floating point: stack underflow".  Although I think something else is going on.

Comment: I'd guess this is a VS compile because of the `void main() and I'd venture it gives a warning like "warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data" which got ignored.

Comment: input is positive intiger. i gave "2"

Comment: Suspect compiler is linking in an incompatible math library.

Comment: BUT ONLINE COMPILER IS ALSO GIVING "RUNTIME ERROR"

Comment: we can use variable for base right?

Comment: Either 1) the function signature is the problem, try `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` and add `return 0;` at the end. or 2) Code posted here is not the true code. or 3) you have compiler/library problems.

Comment: Yes, the base can be a variable.

Comment: sorry, i am new to programming but, what does "Code posted here is not the true code" mean. standards not followed?

Comment: By "true code", I mean that there may be a difference between what is posted and what you are compiling (aside from indentation).

Comment: No sir! I copied code from this block again and executed the code.

Comment: When I ran your code with ideone.com, it returned "17" for the input of "2" http://ideone.com/sqJlow (I changed `void main()` to `int main()` for C++ standard conformance but that should not affect your problem)

Comment: even i am getting output, but as i said while tracing using f7 or in some online compilers it is showing like that i think.

Comment: how can i put image here in comment,.. i wanted to insert output image,.

Comment: Do you still get the failure when using `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` and `return 0;` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

you have to make `main()` returning an `int`: `int main(void)`

http://ideone.com/7HVbGv

here you can see that your program works. if you change it to `void main()` and remove the `return 0;` you get a runtime error at the end of main.

You should also look for a modern compiler. Turbo C++ 4.5 is 20 years old.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B even Wikipedia says `Turbo C++ was a C++ compiler...` and not `Turbo C++ is a C++ compiler...`

Comment: how can i put image here in comment,.. i wanted to insert output image,.

Comment: @user2714940 You can't. And don't do it. Post the error/output message in your post rather than posting images

Comment: thank you,... the above is right! i am new and didnt knew that! but i cant vote up the ans since i dont have 15 reputations so i have added answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for replies!
it was just changing to **int main()** in online compiler but, in turbo c++ there was some problem with math library.

Comment: "it was just changing to int main() in online compiler" and your comment "No sir! I copied code from this block again and executed the code." are inconsistent.  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this
    sum+=((int)pow(i,4));
instead of 
    sum+=pow(i,4);